# JavaScript/Node + cURL

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, meteor

I have a line of cURL:

```
curl -X POST --form "file=@Calvin Harris - Thinking About You (Tez Cadey Remix)_165299184_soundcloud.mp3" https://api.idolondemand.com/1/api/async/recognizespeech/v1
```

I'm building a hybrid mobile app with Meteor/Ionic as the framework. Therefore, I have access to any Node library that leverages cURL.

Can anyone:

1) Suggest one of the many node-curl libraries
2) Show me how to properly output the above cURL line in the context of the right library?

My primary issue that is stopping me is the `--form` flag. I've poured over several libraries/docs and none explicitly reference how to use this form flag. I cannot drop this flag, it's a requirement of the API.

Comment: Why specifically curl?

Comment: I'm unable to use the IDOL-onDemand API with just a filename. IDOL-onDemand expects to see "multipart/form-data". Perhaps if I can pass this data in with a HTTP POST request, I could avoid cURL.

Comment: Pretty sure you could.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the 'request' library? https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads

Comment: It's one of the ones I read over. I notice it has a "form" section, but it still confuses me. Let's say I have a single input field: <input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">. How can I properly use the request API to capture this form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use node's [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) APIs

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var rs = fs.createReadStream(
  'Calvin Harris - Thinking About You (Tez Cadey Remix)_165299184_soundcloud.mp3'
);

var req = http.request({
  hostname: 'api.idolondemand.com',
  path: '/1/api/async/recognizespeech/v1',
  method: 'POST'
}, function(res) {
  // do something when you get a response
});

rs.pipe(req);
```

Or use the requests module as @ffk mentioned